# Scrollbar that doesn't interfere with text-wrap on hover

Tags: html, css, text, scrollbar

I have the following structure on many of the pages on my blog:

http://jsfiddle.net/gliu/E32Bh/

Basically, boxes with too much text are displayed without vertical scrollbar until the user hovers over them.

There is a problem though. When the scrollbar appears it creates a margin of its own which causes the text to wrap differently.

I need a solution where the scrollbar will not have an effect on text wrapping. The user must still be able to scroll through the DIV. I'd prefer not to see the scrollbar hidden, but if that's the only way to do it, then go for it. If there's a pure CSS/HTML solution to this, that will be the best!

Code (since StackOverflow insists upon it)

```
<p>Notice how the text gets wrapped differently once you hover over the div:</p>
<div id="scroller">
   <div class="content">
        Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
    </div>
</div>

div#scroller {
    position: absolute;
    width: 75%;
    height: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 3px solid gold;
}
div#scroller:hover {
    overflow-y: scroll; /* Display scrollbar on hover only */
}
div.content {
    padding: 1em;    
    background: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick way to fix this is to always display a scrollbar even if there is nothing to scroll. This prevents content shifting left and right.

CSS: `overflow-y: scroll;`

Comment: As a side note, when I tested your jsfiddle on my local Chrome, it seems to work as you thought... The text doesn't seem to wrap differently.

Comment: That is true, but browsers behave differently (Firefox user here.) The website must be consistent no matter the browser.

Edit: You can't see the effects of the scrollbar until you scroll down a little, for me at least.

Comment: I understand it might look different to me, but using the `overflow-y: scroll;` works on all browsers if you have to use it.

Comment: Another important note: if you put 'overflow-y: scroll' in css, then the vertical scrollbar will show up even if the content doesn't overflow the DIV. (Tested on Firefox)